# How to sort multi-array using similar_text()?

Tags: php

How can sort an array by an objects value?

```
$cars = array
(
array("Volvo",22,18),
array("BMWx",15,13),
array("Saabmove",5,2),
array("Land Rovermove",17,15)
);
```

Array should be in order based on similarity of value.

Comment: `uasort`, `uksort`, and `usort` all sort arrays according to a user passed comparison function (by value while maintaining keys, by key, and by value without maintaining keys, respectively) - how you define "similarity of value" is something _you_ need to define.

Comment: Did you even bother to do a web search or read the documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

example for sorting multi array by similar_text https://3v4l.org/XUBDD#output

```
$json = '{
    "result": {
        "anime": [
            {
                "rowid": "2",
                "title": "Dusk Maiden of Amnesia",
                "pic": "\/\/i.imgur.com\/J4HRnHP.jpg",
                "slug": "Dusk-Maiden-of-Amnesia-dub",
                "year": "2012",
                "status": "done",
                "descript": "The story revolves around a first-year middle school student, Teiichi Niiya who had just enrolled at Seikyou Private Academy. When he gets lost in one of the schools old buildings, he meets a girl named Yuuko Kanoe who reveals herself as a ghost with no memories. Teiichi then decides to investigate her death by looking through the schools seven mysteries revolving around her. Throughout the story, Teiichi and Yuuko discover the truth about these ghost stories while helping those who are troubled.",
                "tags": "Mystery,,Romance,,School Club,,School Life,,Supernatural,,High School"
            },
            {
                "rowid": "12",
                "title": "Accel World",
                "pic": "https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/65gNsOX.png",
                "slug": "Accel-World-dub",
                "year": "2012",
                "status": "done",
                "descript": "Haruyuki+%22Haru%22+Arita+is+a+short%2C+overweight+boy+who+is+frequently+ridiculed+by+delinquents+at+the+Umesato+Junior+High+School.+Using+his+Neuro+Linker+to+escape+the+torment+of+real+life%2C+he+logs+onto+the+school%27s+Local+Network+cyberspace+where+he+always+plays+virtual+squash+alone%2C+and+his+innate+video+game+skills+bring+him+to+the+attention+of+Kuroyukihime+%28literally+meaning+%22Black+Snow+Princess%22%29%2C+the+school%27s+popular%2C+highly+intellectual+and+attractive+female+Student+Council+Vice-President.++After+helping+him+against+the+delinquents%2C+Kuroyukihime+introduces+Haruyuki+to+Brain+Burst%2C+a+secret+program+that+is+able+to+accelerate+the+human+cognitive+process+to+the+point+at+which+time+appears+to+stop.+Haruyuki+soon+learns+that+Brain+Burst+is+more+than+just+a+program%2C+but+an+Augmented+Reality+Massively+Multiplayer+Online+%28ARMMO%29+Fighting+Game+where+people+fight+each+other+in+fierce+duels+in+order+to+obtain+Burst+Points+which+can+be+spent+for+acceleration+abilities+in+the+real+world.",
                "tags": "Action,,Sci Fi,,Based On A Light Novel,,Futuristic,,Virtual Reality"
            },
            {
                "rowid": "7",
                "title": "Parasyte the maxim",
                "pic": "https:\/\/i.imgur.com\/AY7WkqY.jpg",
                "slug": "Parasyte-the-maxim-dub",
                "year": "2014",
                "status": "done",
                "descript": "17-year-old+Izumi+Shinichi+lives+with+his+mother+and+father+in+a+quiet+neighborhood+in+Tokyo.+One+night%2C+worm-like+aliens+called+Parasytes+invade+Earth%2C+taking+over+the+brains+of+human+hosts+by+entering+through+their+ears+or+noses.+One+Parasyte+attempts+to+crawl+into+Shinichi%27s+ear+while+he+sleeps%2C+but+fails+since+he+is+wearing+headphones%2C+and+enters+his+body+by+burrowing+into+his+arm+instead%2C+taking+over+his+right+hand+and+is+named+Migi.+Because+Shinichi+was+able+to+prevent+Migi+from+traveling+further+up+into+his+brain%2C+both+beings+retain+their+separate+intellect+and+personality.+As+the+duo+encounter+other+Parasytes%2C+they+capitalize+on+their+strange+situation+and+gradually+form+a+strong+bond%2C+working+together+to+survive.+This+gives+them+an+edge+in+battling+other+Parasytes%2C+who+frequently+attack+the+pair+upon+realization+that+Shinichi%27s+human+brain+is+still+intact.+Shinichi+feels+compelled+to+fight+other+Parasytes%2C+who+devour+humans+as+food%2C+while+enlisting+Migi%27s+help.",
                "tags": "Action,,Horror,,Sci Fi,,Aliens,,Body Sharing,,Bullying,,Explicit Violence,,Psychological"
            }
        ],
        "Current_page": "1",
        "Total_Pages": 75,
        "PerPage": 3,
        "Total": 224
    }
}';
$userInput = "maxim";
$jsonf = json_decode($json, true);
  usort($jsonf['result']['anime'], function ($a, $b) use ($userInput) {
    similar_text($userInput, $a['title'], $percentA);
    similar_text($userInput, $b['title'], $percentB);

    return $percentA === $percentB ? 0 : ($percentA > $percentB ? -1 : 1);
}); 
echo json_encode($jsonf);
```